# Getting error "Transaction Oversize" while creating a smart contract in Hedera blockchain

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

My bin file size is 18kb only. I also get a solution to use IPFS but don't know how to use it. If there is any reference for using IPFS then share me plz. :

**Error: PrecheckStatusError: transaction 0.0.34898094@1653658245.135892060 failed precheck with status TRANSACTION_OVERSIZE**

Here is my code :

```
const {
  AccountId,
  PrivateKey,
  Client,
  FileCreateTransaction,
  ContractCreateTransaction,
  ContractFunctionParameters,
  ContractExecuteTransaction,
  ContractCallQuery,
  Hbar
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");
const fs = require("fs");

const operatorId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_ID);
const operatorKey = PrivateKey.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_PVKEY);
const client = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(operatorId, operatorKey);


async function main() {
  // Import the compiled contract bytecode
  const contractBytecode = fs.readFileSync("first_contract_sol_ABC_TOKEN.bin");
  // Create a file on Hedera and store the bytecode
  const fileCreateTx = new FileCreateTransaction().setContents(contractBytecode).setKeys([operatorKey]).setMaxTransactionFee(new Hbar(1))
    .freezeWith(client);
  const fileCreateSign = await fileCreateTx.sign(operatorKey);
  console.log(Date.now() / 1000);
  const fileCreateSubmit = await fileCreateSign.execute(client);
  const fileCreateRx = await fileCreateSubmit.getReceipt(client);
  const bytecodeFileId = fileCreateRx.fileId;
  console.log(`- The bytecode file ID is: ${bytecodeFileId} \n`);  

    // Instantiate the smart contract
    const contractInstantiateTx = new ContractCreateTransaction()
    .setBytecodeFileId(bytecodeFileId)
    .setGas(100000)
    .setConstructorParameters(
      new ContractFunctionParameters().addString("Alice").addUint256(111111)
    );
  const contractInstantiateSubmit = await contractInstantiateTx.execute(client);
  const contractInstantiateRx = await contractInstantiateSubmit.getReceipt(
    client
  );
  const contractId = contractInstantiateRx.contractId;
  const contractAddress = contractId.toSolidityAddress();
  console.log(`- The smart contract ID is: ${contractId} \n`);
  console.log(`- Smart contract ID in Solidity format: ${contractAddress} \n`);

}
main();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are hitting the TRANSACTION_OVERSIZE error because Hedera transactions have a 6kb size limit including all signatures.

If the compiled bytecode for your contract is relatively large, then you will need to create a file on Hedera, then append the contents in multiple chunks, and then create the contract.

The SDK now handles those 3 steps for you when you use `ContractCreateFlow()`.Here's an example:

```
const contractCreate = new ContractCreateFlow()
    .setGas(100000)
    .setBytecode(bytecode);

//Sign the transaction with the client operator key and submit to a Hedera network
const txResponse = contractCreate.execute(client);

//Get the receipt of the transaction
const receipt = (await txResponse).getReceipt(client);
```

Comment: Even with contractCreateFlow instead of contractCreateTransaction, Im still getting transaction oversize error