# Hedera Transaction Oversize error : TypeError: ContractCreateFlow is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

The below code throws "Transaction Oversize" error

```
const contractBytecode = fs.readFileSync("TestToken_sol_TestToken.bin");
const fileCreateTx = new FileCreateTransaction()
    .setContents(contractBytecode)
    .setKeys([operatorKey])
    .freezeWith(client);    
const fileCreateSign = await fileCreateTx.sign(operatorKey);
const fileCreateSubmit = await fileCreateSign.execute(client);
const fileCreateRx = await fileCreateSubmit.getReceipt(client);
const bytecodeFileId = fileCreateRx.fileId;
console.log(`- The bytecode file ID is: ${bytecodeFileId} \n`);
```

But trying out solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72663612/7897684), I ran into this new error "ContractCreateFlow is not a constructor" :

```
const contractInstantiateTx = new ContractCreateFlow()
.setGas(100000)
.setBytecode(contractBytecode)

const contractInstantiateSubmit = await contractInstantiateTx.execute(client);
const contractInstantiateRx = await contractInstantiateSubmit.getReceipt(client);

const contractId = contractInstantiateRx.contractId;
const contractAddress = contractId.toSolidityAddress();
console.log(`- The smart contract ID is: ${contractId} \n`);
console.log(`- The smart contract ID in Solidity format is: ${contractAddress} \n`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this answer: [Getting error "Transaction Oversize" while creating a smart contract in Hedera blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406476/getting-error-transaction-oversize-while-creating-a-smart-contract-in-hedera-b)
You may need to import the `ContractCreateFlow()` module into your program from the SDK. Check the SDK version you're using as `ContractCreateFlow()` was introduced in v2.14 of the JS SDK.

As an alternative, see this example if you wish to use FileCreate, FileAppend, and Contract create modules:

```
//Create a file on Hedera and store the hex-encoded bytecode
const fileCreateTx = await new FileCreateTransaction().setKeys([adminKey]).execute(client);
const fileCreateRx = await fileCreateTx.getReceipt(client);
const bytecodeFileId = fileCreateRx.fileId;
console.log(`- The smart contract bytecode file ID is: ${bytecodeFileId}`);

// Append contents to the file
const fileAppendTx = await new FileAppendTransaction()
    .setFileId(bytecodeFileId)
    .setContents(bytecode)
    .setMaxChunks(10)
    .setMaxTransactionFee(new Hbar(2))
    .execute(client);
await fileAppendTx.getReceipt(client);
console.log(`- Content added`);

console.log(`\nSTEP 2 - Create contract`);
const contractCreateTx = await new ContractCreateTransaction()
    .setAdminKey(adminKey)
    .setBytecodeFileId(bytecodeFileId)
    .setGas(100000)
    .execute(client);

const contractCreateRx = await contractCreateTx.getReceipt(client);
const contractId = contractCreateRx.contractId.toString();
console.log(`- Contract created ${contractId}`);
```

If you don't use `ContractCreateFlow()`, you first create an empty file, then append content (by chunks), and then create the contract - as shown by the code above.